# Problem with Ryanair bus transfer

Tags: airport-transfer, buses, ryanair

An Italian friend recently travelled to London.  They purchased tickets for an airport transfer bus. They were not allowed to board the bus. They were told they had bought "standby tickets". They had to spend £142 on train and underground tickets instead.
Ryanair are claiming that all tickets for the airport bus are standby, which seems ridiculous as surely everyone wants to be on their way as soon as possible after landing! They also sell tickets for specific timed services, which is misleading if this is the case.
I just tried to do a mock booking for tickets so that I could check if they mentioned that the tickets were standby tickets. Nothing. I read the T&Cs before you make payment. Nothing. Has anyone else come across this or know what we can do?

Comment: Transfer to where to where ? A one way ticket to London-Liverpool St from Stansted (main RyanAir hub) costs ~£22/person, Gatwick and Luton are afaik similarly priced, so where does the £142 come from ?

Comment: While you didn't find 'standby' in the T&C do they say there is no guarantee to be conveyed on any particular bus? Did they book actual seats on the bus? Unless all seats must be booked in advance, it is logistically impossible to know what the demand will be. OTOH it's impossible for a passenger to know if they can be on time for a particular bus.

Comment: Did you get a refund for the unused ticket? Demanding that is all you can do IMHO.

Comment: Hi. He was advised to swipe his debit card at the departing station (London Victoria) and was was told he must pay £142 when exiting at the other end (Stansted). He wasn't aware that the ticket didn't guarantee a seat (why would you on an airport transfer)? It wasn't specified, although in the T&Cs it states that the booking doesn’t actually guarantee a booking. So basically, you're paying for something you might not get, even if you book a specific  time. He has spent over £200 for him and his wife to travel back to the airport (including the wasted tickets). Their flights were £68!!

Comment: He hasn't got any refund so far.  Good point actually. Nobody can guarantee being on time for any bus, so a delay means a ticket is no longer valid. If only transport in the UK wasn't so ****ing expensive and they ran shuttle buses at reasonable rates ho ho ho.

Comment: From the amount you quote (£142) and the circumstances you describe, it sounds like your friends were each charged a Penalty Fare when they arrived at Stansted. A Penalty Fare is £50 plus the applicable single fare - £21.90 in this case. Unfortunately, Oyster or contactless cards cannot be used when travelling to Stansted Airport and therefore they did not have a valid ticket. They should have bought a ticket from a ticket machine or app; a single for two people is only £38.40. Perhaps something to consider for next time.

Comment: Exactly, with services departing from Stansted for London every few minutes, it makes little sense to book non-refundable tickets on a particular bus, in advance. Were they that much cheaper than the regular fare? I doubt it.